# Spivak's Calculus 2nd ed - Ch. 23 - pg 480 - Thm 9 - Question on the proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

The following is a proof for a theorem in *Spivak's Calculus   - Ch. 22*:

[image]

There are two pieces of the proof I don't follow, first is $(1)$ where it states it follows that

$$ \sum_{i \ \text{or}\ j >L}|a_{i}| \cdot |b_{j}| \leq \epsilon$$

comes from. Because I don't see directly how to relate this to the inequality above it in the proof.

And the reasoning for $(3)$. I get that we are given that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$ both converge absolutely individually, so are we just using the idea that since they both converge individually then their product will also converge? and we write that using the partial sum notation where since they converge, there exists $i,j > L$ such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}b_{j} - \sum_{i=1}^{L}a_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{L}b_{j}| < \epsilon$$?

Answer (score 1):

For (1), note that

$$S_{L'}=\left|\sum_{i=1}^{L'}|a_i|\sum_{j=1}^{L'}|b_j| - \sum_{i=1}^{L}|a_i|\sum_{j=1}^{L}|b_j| \right| = \sum_{i=L+1}^{L'}|a_i|\sum_{j=1}^{L'}|b_j|+ \sum_{i=1}^{L}|a_i|\sum_{j=L+1}^{L'}|b_j| < \epsilon$$

Since $S_{L'}$ is a sum of nonnegative terms it is monotone increasing with respect to index $L'$. As it is also bounded above the sequence $(S_{L'})$ converges with

$$\sum_{i \text{ or } j >L}|a_i| |b_j|= \lim_{L' \to \infty}S_{L'} \leqslant \epsilon$$.

Comment: If $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$ and $x_n < \epsilon$ for all $n$, then $x \leqslant \epsilon$.  Strict inequality may be lost in the limit. ($1 - 1/n <1$ and $1-1/n \to 1$).

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) when I worked out the absolute value expression you have above I got: $\sum_{i=L+1}^{L'}|a_i|\sum_{j=1}^{L'}|b_j|- \sum_{i=1}^{L}|a_i|\sum_{j=L+1}^{L'}|b_j|$. Did you mean: $\sum_{i=L+1}^{L'}|a_i|\sum_{j=1}^{L'}|b_j|- \sum_{i=1}^{L}|a_i|\sum_{j=L+1}^{L'}|b_j| \leq \sum_{i=L+1}^{L'}|a_i|\sum_{j=1}^{L'}|b_j|+ \sum_{i=1}^{L}|a_i|\sum_{j=L+1}^{L'}|b_j|$?       

2) How do you know $S_{L'}$ is bounded above?    

3) Where did the motivation for breaking up the sum in the way you did to have things cancel out come from? I would never have thought that.

Comment: You have a sum of all of the elements $|a_i||b_j|$ in an $L' \times L'$ matrix minus the sum of the elements in the the $L \times L$ submatrix formed from the first $L$ rows and   $L$ columns.  What is left should be the sum of elements in rows with indexes $L+1, \ldots, L'$ and columns $1, \ldots L'$ and the sum of elements in rows $1, \ldots, L$ and columns $L+1,\ldots, L'$.  You could split it differently, but only nonnegative terms remain.

Comment: Take $L=1$ and $L'=2$. You get $|a_1||b_1| + |a_1||b_2| + |a_2||b_1| + |a_2| |b_2| - |a_1||b_1| = |a_1||b_2| + |a_2||b_1| + |a_2| |b_2|$

Answer (score 1):

You have$$\sum_{i\text{ or }j>L}|a_i|.|b_j|\leqslant\frac\varepsilon2$$because, for any finite set $F$ of pairs $(i,j)$ in which $i>L$ or $j>L$, you take $L'$ so large that for every $(i,j)\in F$ you have $i,j\leqslant L'$ (it's possible, since $F$ is finite) and then$$\sum_{(i,j)\in F}|a_i|.|b_j|\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^{L'}|a_i|.\sum_{j=1}^{L'}|b_j|-\sum_{i=1}^L|a_i|.\sum_{j=1}^L|b_j|\leqslant\frac\varepsilon2.$$

The other inequality follws from the fact that$$\lim_{L\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^L|a_i|.\sum_{j=1}^L|b_j|=\sum_{i=1}^\infty|a_i|.\sum_{j=1}^\infty|b_j|.$$

Comment: Is $\sum_{(i,j)\in F}|a_i|.|b_j|$ a compact way of writing $\sum_{i = L +1}^{N}|a_{i}|\sum_{j = L +1}^{N}|b_{j}|$? where $N$ is just some value such that $N < L'$. Intuitively I get the idea: "subtracting from something so large will not change the inequality".

Comment: No. It0s the sum of all products $|a_i|.|b_j|$ with $(i,j)\in F$. It cannot possigly be $\sum_{i=L+1}^n|a_i|\sum_{j=L+1}^N|b_j|$ since this expression doesn't even mention $F$.

Comment: So since $F$ is finite I will only have a finite amount of $|a_{i}||b_{j}|$ terms and as a result a finite sum of them. In comparison, $\sum_{i=L+1}^n|a_i|\cdot \sum_{j=L+1}^N|b_j|$ contains all of the terms from $\sum_{(i,j) \in F}|a_{i}||b_{j}|$ but also more terms on top of that since $L'$ is much larger? Is that the right thinking?